# Sharepoint statusbar event / trigger

Tags: sharepoint

is there a way to trigger a javascript when the statusbar appear?

I need to calculate the content height when the statusbar gets displayed.

**SOLUTION**
I override the SP function.

Standard override method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a documented API but you can try to handle resize event of "pageStatusBar", the statusbar container.